# Posgre partition by and group where range is true?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, partition

I have a table that I would like to group by ranges, and display how many installers have installations that fall into a specific range. For this example, the ranges are [1-3] and [4-5]

```
Installer Size
Ben       5
Ben       5
Sam       4
Sam       1
Ben       1
Sam       2
Sam       NULL
```

Here is what I would like to see using an `over partition by` and `count(*)`:

```
Installer  CounOf[1-3]  CountOf[4-5]
Ben        1              2
Sam        2              1
```

How would I write this query?

Answer (score 2):

For this task you don't need window functions (functions that use `over()` clause). You can use conditional aggregation instead; Postgres' `filter()` clause comes handy for this:

```
select 
    installer,
    count(*) filter(where size between 1 and 3) count_of_1_3,
    count(*) filter(where size between 4 and 5) count_of_4_5
from mytable
group by installer
order by installer
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8dc5bd07451eb6e1ebbe781a2836e2e6)**:

```
installer | count_of_1_3 | count_of_4_5
:-------- | -----------: | -----------:
Ben       |            1 |            2
Sam       |            2 |            1
```